# How to copy an excel worksheet containing a powerquery so that the query on the new worksheet is independent from the query on the original worksheet

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have an excel workbook with a worksheet called "Template".  The "Template" worksheet has a powerquery query called "fruits".  The "fruits" query was created by invoking a custom query function.  The custom query function itself refers to a query parameter to get a URL.  When I edit the "fruits" query, in the powerquery formula bar I can change a parameter with a value of "apples" to a different fruit e.g. "bananas" and the data will update accordingly.  The "Template" worksheet has lots of worksheet formulas that refer to the data in the "fruits" query.  I want to copy the "Template" worksheet within the same workbook such that the new worksheet contains a completely independent copy of the query so on the "Template" worksheet I can have "apples" data and on the new worksheet I can have "bananas" data.  Currently both worksheets display the data from the original fruits query and any change in the original is reflected in both worksheets.

I have tried...

1. Copy the workbook to a new workbook.  This just results in a "The connection could not be refreshed.  This problem could occur if the connection was copied from another workbook or the workbook was created in a newer version of Excel."  This is not actually what I want (separate workbooks) my web search revealed many claims that I could copy to a new workbook and the query would be independent.
2. Before doing 1, in the query pane copy all the building-block queries from the original workbook to the new workbook.  Same error as #1
3. Copy the worksheet within the same workbook.  in the query pane right click "fruits" query and 'duplicate' and try and "close and load to..." the new worksheet to try and override the query.  I get an error ""Invalid Table Range. The selected range is invalid. A table cannot overlap a range that contains a PivotTable report, query results, protected cells or another table".
4. do #3 but this time use "convert to range" to turn make the data to static before duplicating the query.  Same error message as #3.
5. do #4 but after "convert to range" actually clear the cells so the worksheet formulas are pointing to blank cells.  When I duplicate the query is does load to the worksheet but in doing so it inserts new columns so that the worksheet formulas are still pointing at blank cells whereas I need them pointing to the new data cells.

I am using Excel 2013.

Edit: another attempt (after @Peter's suggestion).

6. Do #5 but when loading to worksheet choose **Add this data to the data model**.  Query is on worksheet as I expected and formulas on the worksheet point to the correct cells in the query table, however, the formulas adjacent to the table have been converted from table column notation to absolute cell notation (i.e. 'Template (2)!$F$26').  So while all appears well, if I refresh the query and the rows change then the adjacent column won't fill the formulas down.  I can manually edit the formulas but I am hoping there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Copy** your *Template* worksheet to *Template (2)*.
2. **Duplicate** your *fruits* query in PowerQuery and change the fruit to bananas in *fruits (2)*.
3. **Close & Load To** *Template (2)*

Comment: I can  close & Load To a blank part of Template (2), but I need the query results to override the query results that are already there (otherwise my other formulas don't point to the correct cells.  If i close and load to the original location on Template (2) then i get the "Invalid Table Range. The selected range is invalid. A table cannot overlap a range that contains a PivotTable report, query results, protected cells or another table" error again.

Comment: I know, there is an easy workaround for that. But you don't seem to give credits to voluntary help.

Comment: Hi @Peter, sorry for my terse words.  Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried it and it didn't work for me.  I tried it with a variation (Load to blank cells) and it while it loaded it wasn't what I was after as I need my formulas to point to the data.  If you have further clarification for making it work I'd love to hear it (and mark the question as answered in a heartbeat!)